# Replacing varying delimiters using sed or tr

Tags: sed, newline, tr

I need to convert a list of IDs from using a delimiter consisting of `,` and/or `\r\n` or `\n` to using `,|`.  (essentially: `s/[,\r\n]+/,\|/g` without a trailing `|`)

Example input data:

```
123,456,789,012
```

or

```
123,
456
789,
012
```

and I need the resulting output to be `123,|456,|798,|012,`: a comma ending each field, and a pipe separating them.

This seems really simple to do, but I'm quite stumped on how to manage this.  I've tried ... quite a few ways, actually, but nothing seems to work.  Here are a few examples:

1. `sed "s/[,\r\n]+/,\|/g" < filename` does not match any of the delimiters.
2. `sed "s/(,|,?\r?\n?)/,\|/g"` does not match anything either.
3. `tr -t "(,?(\r|\n)+)" ",\|"` and `tr -t "[,\r\n]+" ",\|"` only replace `,`
4. `tr "(,|\r?\n)" ",\|"` works correctly with `,` but with `,\n` and `,\r\n` it replaces the matched characters with multiple bars. Ex: `123|||456|||789|||012|`
5. Getting more complex: `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g"` (Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)) replaces `\n` correctly with `,` but does not work with `\r\n`.  Replacing the `\n` with `[,\r\n]` simply returns the input.

I'm stumped.  Can anyone offer some help or advice on this?

Comment: So the output doesn't have a pipe at the end?  In the output, you have `,` marking the end of each field, and `|` separating pairs of fields?

Comment: Correct!  I would have been clearer about that in my post, but I was being rushed out the door at work. :(

Comment: Thanks!  and yep.  I was waiting until I could test it at work today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your sample output, it seems that the output doesn't have a pipe at the end; you have `,` marking the end of each field, and `|` separating pairs of fields.  For that specification, this works with `tr` and `sed`:

```
$ x="123,
> 456
> 789,
> 012"
$ echo "$x" | tr -s '\r\n' ',' | sed 's/,\(.\)/,|\1/g'
123,|456,|789,|012,
$
```

The `tr` command replaces newline and carriage return with comma, squeezing (`-s`) duplicates.  The `sed` command looks for a comma followed by another character and replaces it with `,|`.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is normalize the \r\n sequence to \n to get rid of one alternative (and increase the speed of the next step).

```
perl -pi -e 'BEGIN { $/ = undef; } s/\r\n/\n/g; s/[,\n]/,|/g;'
```

Update: from your examples, it looks like you meant to replace multiple occurrences of delimiters with nothing in between them with a single occurence of ,| If that is what you want to do, then change the command to this:

```
perl -pi -e 'BEGIN { $/ = undef; } END { print ",\n"; } s/\r\n/\n/g; s/[,\n]+/,|/g;'
```

Also, you want a trailing , after the last field.

Comment: Sadly, the target environment does not have access to perl.